# SSRS encryption keys are broken

Tags: ssrs-2016

I had an SSRS service account password expire. This is on an Azure Windows server.

I've tried the following:

- Updating the password caused "The report server can’t access or use the encryption key"
- Attempting to delete the key via all the normal methods fails.
- Manually deleting the key (keys table) doesn't give me an option to re-create a new one.

The only solution I can think of at this point is un-installing and reinstalling SSRS.

Is there a better way, or is this approach even likely to work?

Answer (score 1):

Ended up not trying the uninstall/reinstall of SSRS.

Here's what got me working:

- Stop SSRS service
- detach reporting service databases
- restart SSRS -- it complains about missing DBs
- stop SSRS
- reattach
- restart SSRS
- Using SSRS configuration wizard, re-point SSRS to its databases
- Now I was able to delete the encryption keys

This is obviously a hack solution and fails to identify what went wrong in the first place, but it worked

Comment: Thanks that worked for me! Still as you said, it feels like a hack. SSRS is extremely fussy.